# Можно ли "оживлять" совокупность людей ("группа", "команда")?

Tags: синтаксис, морфология

Например: "*Группа/команда состояла из десяти мужчин. **Группа была заинтересована**. **Команда не показывала признаков усталости***".

Корректны ли подобные фразы? Можно ли так писать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наименование союза людей командой или группой показывает сплочённость, рассматривает группу/команду не как набор личностей, а как единый организм. Если вам важно подчеркнуть эту сплочённость, то хорошо писать так, как указали в примере.

При этом стирается индивидуальность, сравните: *Группа состояла из десяти мужчин. Все были заинтересованы.* — возможно, каждый был заинтересован по своей причине, то есть видим не просто группу как единое целое, а группу как союз личностей.

Подобный вопрос поднимается в правилах о выборе числа сказуемого:

> <Согласование по смыслу предпочтительно,> если нужно подчеркнуть
> раздельность действий каждого действующего лица, называемого
> подлежащим, а также подчеркнуть активность действующих лиц: *Ряд
> сотрудников нашей организации выступили с инициативой*; ср.: *В прошлом
> году было построено множество дорог.*